# Infinite algebraic field extension of a finite field is normal and separable

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, separable-extension

I am trying to prove that every infinite algebraic field extension $K$ of a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ is separable and normal. I know how to do it for finite $K$, but I am struggling to see why the infinite case is also true. I have seen the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065348/infinite-algebraic-extension-of-a-finite-field), but it does not help. I think I should prove that $K$ is an infinite union of finite fields $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, where $p$ is prime, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Use that you know it for $K$ finite. Separability: $\forall x\in K\quad\mathbb F(x)$ is separable over $\mathbb F$ hence so is $x$. Normality:  $\forall x\in K\quad\mathbb F(x)$ is normal over $\mathbb F$ hence $K$ contains all conjugates of $x$ over $\mathbb F$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, can you be more specific? Why is the first argument true? $\mathbb{F}(x)$ is infinite, isn't it?

Comment: It is finite, since $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F$ (by hypothesis on $K$).

Comment: Your "I think" part is not quite correct. Rather, let $\mathbb{F}$ be of order $p^{f}$, for some prime $f$. Then for every $\alpha$ in $K$ we have that $\mathbb{F}(\alpha)$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}$ of some finite degree $a$, and thus a field of order $p^{fa}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I apologize, I confused your notation $x$. I can understand the argument for separability. For normality, i cannot understand it because I have a different definition for normality. Let $f\in \mathbb{F}[X]$ an irreducible polynomial that admits a zero in $a\in K$. Then, since $\mathbb{F}(a)$ is finite, it is normal, so this polynomial decomposes over this field, hence also in $K$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, and your definition of normality is equivalent to mine ("$K$ contains all conjugates of $x$" is equivalent to: "the minimal polynomial of $x$ decomposes in $K$")

Comment: I would also like to learn your definition. What does "all conjugates of x over $\mathbb{F}$" really mean here?

Comment: If you prefer: everything lives inside "the" algebraic closure of $\mathbb F$, where "the conjugates of $x$" are the roots of its minimal polynomial.

Comment: I cannot really see why $K$ is inside the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Because the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) contains all algebraic extensions.